# How to use d3 and date format with years before Christ?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have some data in JSON format I need to import it to build a scatter plot with [d3](http://d3js.org/). The problem is that the records have some dates referred to years before Christ born, for example 400 B.C. Is it possible to format it in a way that d3 accepts?

Comment: 400 BC = -400 AD, basically. it's only ad/bc because most people seem to have trouble with negative numbers.

Comment: @MarcB but the Era isn't part of any date format JavaScript understands, is it?

Comment: no, it's not. `d = new Date(); d.setYear(-200); d.toISOString()` gives you `-0200-12-23T15:38:58.184Z`. You'll have to manually hack up the string to change BC dates into "negative AD" dates.